# Accordion menu in windows phone 8 by using webbrowser control

Tags: c#, javascript, html, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I am using the following HTML page to make an accordion control:

```
<!DOCTYPE >
<html >
<head >
    <title></title>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" >
            function Show() {
                document.getElementById("tdfirst").style.display = 'block';

            }
            function Hide() {
                document.getElementById("tdfirst").style.display = 'none';
            }
            function Show2() {
                document.getElementById("tdsecond").style.display = 'block';
            }
            function Hide2() {
                document.getElementById("tdsecond").style.display = 'none';
            }
            function Show3() {
                document.getElementById("tdthird").style.display = 'block';
            }
            function Hide3() {
                document.getElementById("tdthird").style.display = 'none';
            }
 </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1 {
            width: 164px;
        }
        .style2
        {
            height: 98px;

        }
        .style3
        {
            width: 110px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table>
    <tr style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin; border-color: inherit;">
    <div id="div1" >
    <td class="style1" 
            style="border: thin solid #000000; text-align: right;">
        <table><tr><td>Menu1</td><td class="style3">
            <img alt="" onclick="Show()" src="Image/down%20arrow.jpg" 
                style="height: 15px; margin-left: 0px"  /><img 
                alt="" onclick="Hide()"  src="Image/up%20arrow.jpg" style="height: 15px" /></td></tr></table> </td>
        </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <div id="div2">
    <td id="tdfirst" class="style2"  
            style="border: thin solid #000080; text-align: left;display:none;"; >SubMenu1</td>
    </div>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
    <table>
    <tr style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin; border-color: inherit;">
    <div id="div3" >
    <td class="style1" 
            style="border: thin solid #000000; text-align: right;">
        <table><tr><td>Menu2</td><td class="style3">
            <img  alt="" onclick="Show2()" src="Image/down%20arrow.jpg" 
                style="height: 15px; margin-left: 0px"  /><img 
                alt="" onclick="Hide2()"  src="Image/up%20arrow.jpg" style="height: 15px" /></td></tr></table> </td>
        </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <div id="div4">
    <td id="tdsecond" class="style2"  
            style="border: thin solid #000080; text-align: left;display:none;"; >SubMenu2</td>
    </div>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
    <tr style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin; border-color: inherit;">
    <div id="div5" >
    <td class="style1" 
            style="border: thin solid #000000; text-align: right;">
        <table><tr><td>Menu3</td><td class="style3">
            <img id="imgdown" alt="" onclick="Show3()" src="Image/down%20arrow.jpg" 
                style="height: 15px; margin-left: 0px"  /><img id="imgup"
                alt="" onclick="Hide3()"  src="Image/up%20arrow.jpg" style="height: 15px" /></td></tr></table> </td>
        </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <div id="div6">
    <td id="tdthird" class="style2"  
            style="border: thin solid #000080; text-align: left;display:none;"; >SubMenu3</td>
    </div>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
    </html>
```

When I try to display this HTML in a `WebBrowser` control, nothing appears and the control is blank.

XAML:

```
<phone:WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="webBrowser1" Grid.Row="1" IsScriptEnabled="True" />
```

.cs:

`webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("/Html_Pages/AboutUs.html", UriKind.Relative));`

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I'm using VS2012 and the WP8 emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope This will help you. `NavigateToString()`

```
private void goNavigateToStringButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Load HTML document as a string
    Uri uri = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/HTMLDocumentWithoutScript.html", UriKind.Absolute);
    Stream stream = Application.GetResourceStream(uri).Stream;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
      // Navigate to HTML document string
      this.webBrowser.NavigateToString(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

from : [NavigateToString() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring.aspx)